# Displaying Jquery form validation error messages on the right side of form elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I have a form and I am using this [jquery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate it. The validation is working perfectly but the problem is the error messages show up at the bottom of my form elements. I am trying to display it on the right side of form elements.

Could you please help me?

Please check the entire code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SxFBF/)

My Form

```
<form id="commentForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="input">Name <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
       <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="input-small required" id="name" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="input">Email <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
       <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="input-small required email" id="email" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="submit"  />

</form>
```

CSS for error

```
form label.error{font:10px Tahoma,sans-serif;color:#ED7476;margin-left:5px}
form input.error,form input.error:hover,form input.error:focus,form select.error,
form textarea.error{border:1px solid #ED7476;background:#FFEDED}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved by giving the `display:inline;` to the `label.error` class in css.

```
form label.error{
    font:10px Tahoma,sans-serif;
    color:#ED7476;
    margin-left:5px;
    display:inline;
}
```

[Check out the modified fiddle sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/SxFBF/1/).

Answer (score 1):

using `display: inline-block` or `display: inline` for span error

```
form label.error { display:inline-block;
font:10px Tahoma,sans-serif;
color:#ED7476;
margin-left:5px }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/SxFBF/2/)